# Residue theorem and combinatoric identities

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

[image]
As highlighted, I don't quite follow the link from the contour integral to where summation terms are introduced and finally to the combinatoric identity although I do understand why the last step holds("since..")~

Comment: It would be best to edit this question and rewrite the mathematical formulas rather than using scanned images.

Answer (score 3):

It is just expansions of $(1+\epsilon)^n$

$$(1+\epsilon)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\epsilon^k$$

$$(1+\frac{1}{\epsilon})^n=\sum_{l=0}^n\binom{n}{l}\epsilon^{-l}$$

Multiply the two together:

$$(1+\epsilon)^n \cdot (1+\frac{1}{\epsilon})^n=\bigg(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\epsilon^k\bigg)\cdot \bigg(\sum_{l=0}^n\binom{n}{l}\epsilon^{-l}\bigg)$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{l=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{l}\epsilon^{k-l}$$

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the clarification, i just posted another related qns that I still have doubts about ><

Answer (score 3):

It's a basic fact from complex analysis that if $C$ is a closed contour around $a$, then

$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{C} (z-a)^{k} dz=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & k=-1. \\
0 & \mbox{otherwise.}
\end{array}
\right.
$

This is discussed in many introductory textbooks on complex analysis but deriving it would take far more space than is reasonable for this site.

If you're willing to accept the Cauchy formula stated above, then the rest of the derivation isn't too hard.

$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{C} \frac{1}{z} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{l} z^{k-l} dz=
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{l} \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{C} z^{k-l-1} dz$

Let

$\delta_{k-l}=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
1 & k-l=0. \\
0 & k-l \neq 0.
\end{array}
\right.
$

$z^{k-l-1}$ will be $z^{-1}$ only when $k=l$.

Thus

$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{C} \frac{1}{z} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{l} z^{k-l} dz=
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{l} \delta_{k-l}.  
$

$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{C} \frac{1}{z} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{l} z^{k-l} dz=
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}^{2}.  
$

Note that there's an error in the source that you've quoted- since $k$ is the index of summation on the previous line, the next line can't simply be $\binom{n}{k}^{2}$.

Comment: Ah I see, then what should the next line be like? Since eventually the identity must hold~

Comment: The last line of my derivation gives you the left hand side of the identity.  The derivation started with the right hand side.  So, we're done.

Comment: Ahh thanks for the clarification, I just posted another related qns that I still have doubts about ><